# Периодически скрипт оставляет подряд много файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу программу для комментирования постов вк на питоне.

Работает вроде корректно, но иногда появляется баг и программа вместо одного комментария начинает строчить много под один пост.

Вот код:

```py
import vk_api
import time
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(login='логин', password='пароль')
vk.auth()

COMMS = ['API', 'VK API', 'опа', 'comment', 'test', 'lll']


def comm(owner_id, post_id, с):
    vk.method('wall.createComment', {'owner_id': owner_id, 'post_id': post_id, 'message': с})


while True:
    try:
        rs = vk.method("newsfeed.get", {"count": 1})
        newsfeed = rs['items'][0]

        message = random.choice(COMMS)

        if newsfeed['comments']['can_post'] == 1 and newsfeed['comments']['count'] == 0:
            owner_id = newsfeed['source_id']
            post_id = newsfeed['post_id']

            comm(owner_id, post_id, message)
            print('Оставлен комментарий {} {} "{}"'.format(owner_id, post_id, message))

    time.sleep(0.5)

except Exception as E:
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что `if newsfeed['items'][0]['comments']['can_post'] == 1 and newsfeed['items'][0]['comments']['count'] == 0:` это проверка что пост можно комментировать и что количество комментариев в нем 0? Похоже, вы на фичу/баг вк натолкнулись. Поэтому я посоветовал бы хранить инфу о посте, в котором скрипт оставил комментарий и проверять через свою базу что еще не оставляли комментария. Кст, эти `newsfeed['items'][0]...` являются повторами и выглядят некрасиво, лучше заменяйте их на осмысленные названия -- код проще

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, нужно чтобы скрипт сам хранил информацию под каким постом он оставлял комментарий.

И я предлагаю следующие варианты этой реализации:

#### Вариант 1. Хранение в памяти скрипта.

Плюсы:

- Это просто
- Код выглядит просто

Минусы:

- После окончания скрипта, тот забудет информацию
- Можно ее куда-нибудь сохранять, например в json
- Если скрипт внезапно завершится, то может не успеть сохранить данные

Код:

```
import vk_api
import time
import random


MY_COMMENTS = []


def comm(owner_id, post_id, message):
    my_comment_id = "{}_{}".(owner_id, post_id)
    
    # Если комментарий уже был нами оставлен
    if my_comment_id in MY_COMMENTS:
        return

    vk.method('wall.createComment', {
        'owner_id': owner_id, 
        'post_id': post_id, 
        'message': message
    })
    print('Оставлен комментарий: {} {} "{}"'.format(owner_id, post_id, message))
    
    MY_COMMENTS.append(my_comment_id)


COMMS = ['API', 'VK API', 'опа', 'comment', 'test', 'lll']

vk = vk_api.VkApi(login = 'логин', password = 'пароль')
vk.auth()

while True:
    try:
        rs = vk.method("newsfeed.get", {"count": 1})
        newsfeed = rs['items'][0]

        message = random.choice(COMMS)

        if newsfeed['comments']['can_post'] == 1 and newsfeed['comments']['count'] == 0:
            owner_id = newsfeed['source_id']
            post_id = newsfeed['post_id']
            
            comm(owner_id, post_id, message)

        time.sleep(0.5)

    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

#### Вариант 2. Хранение в базе данных SQLite

Плюсы:

- Это немного сложнее, чем хранение в памяти
- Нужно знать SQL
- Легко использовать для других целей: хранение настроек, статистики и т.п. Например, можно дополнить, чтобы в базу добавлялся комментарий и дата с временем.

Минусы:

- Код немного усложнится SQL-запросами
- Код немного медленнее будет работать (но разница будет такой маленькой, что в текущем контексте это не важно)
- Базу нужно с собой носить

Код:

```
import vk_api
import time
import random
import sqlite3


def create_connect():
    return sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')


def init_db():
    # Создание базы и таблицы
    with create_connect() as connect:
        connect.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_COMMENTS (
                owner_id INTEGER,
                post_id  INTEGER
            );
        ''')

        connect.commit()


def append_comment_db(owner_id, post_id):
    with create_connect() as connect:
        sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO MY_COMMENTS (owner_id, post_id) VALUES (?, ?)"
        connect.execute(sql, (owner_id, post_id))

        connect.commit()


def has_comment_db(owner_id, post_id):
    with create_connect() as connect:
        sql = "SELECT 1 FROM MY_COMMENTS WHERE owner_id = ? AND post_id = ?"
        has = connect.execute(sql, (owner_id, post_id)).fetchone()
        return bool(has)

        
def comm(owner_id, post_id, message):
    # Если комментарий уже был нами оставлен
    if has_comment_db(owner_id, post_id):
        return

    vk.method('wall.createComment', {
        'owner_id': owner_id, 
        'post_id': post_id, 
        'message': message
    })
    print('Оставлен комментарий: {} {} "{}"'.format(owner_id, post_id, message))
    
    append_comment_db(owner_id, post_id)

    
COMMS = ['API', 'VK API', 'опа', 'comment', 'test', 'lll']

vk = vk_api.VkApi(login = 'логин', password = 'пароль')
vk.auth()

init_db()

while True:
    try:
        rs = vk.method("newsfeed.get", {"count": 1})
        newsfeed = rs['items'][0]

        message = random.choice(COMMS)

        if newsfeed['comments']['can_post'] == 1 and newsfeed['comments']['count'] == 0:
            owner_id = newsfeed['source_id']
            post_id = newsfeed['post_id']
            
            comm(owner_id, post_id, message)

        time.sleep(0.5)

    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

---

**PS.** можно и другие варианты придумать: хранение в удаленной базе данных, хранение на удаленном сервере и т.п.